# Stop Guides From overlapping

Tags: adobe-photoshop, guides

Im trying to find a to stop guides from overlapping when I cut Im using this to do Email Signatures

But I have images That I want to cut and those I dont

Ill attach a screenshot

[image]

I want the Phone number Email and adress to be sliced so I can create Indiviual Links

But the Image on the left and right shouldnt be cut

This is what I mean by overlapping guides I want them to End on the left and right sides before touching the other images

Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you making email signature text in Photoshop at all? The name, job title, phone number, email address and location should all be _text_ in the signature, not images.

Comment: Well for 1, To save time, 2, if done correctly the results are the exact same. 3. When you have extremely "precise designs" it looks closer to what you'd want, 4, You can use any font you like. I can go on, But in essence it just looks better, again im not Designer im the developer and I prefer this

Comment: Well no, the results are not the same. Many email clients will (very sensibly) not download images until prompted by the user, so the user won’t see the name at all (or only as an alt text inside an ugly box). Clicking ‘Download all images’ should not be a requisite for being able to read the name of the person sending you an email, but it will be this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but the slices you create with the *Slice Tool* don't have to follow the guides:

[image]

Comment: if I'm not mistaken there's an option of converting guides to slices and then they can join the unneeded cuts

Comment: Yes @Sergey there is But what Wolff says is true its why I end up doing it that way